# What are the complete intervals of HTTP Status Codes that might occur in REST API?

Tags: http-status-codes, rest

I'm trying to simplify handling of HTTP Status Codes for a REST API.

I would like to know which of the following intervals of status codes have the possibility to occur in REST API?

```
 -Informational responses (100–199)

 -Successful responses (200–299)

 -Redirects (300–399)

 -Client errors (400–499)

 -Server errors (500–599)
```

It is currently handling only 3 intervals of HTTP Status Codes in the following way.

Is it necessary to handle the remaining 2 intervals namely `Informational responses (100–199)` and `Redirects (300–399)`?

I'm really confused and trying to find the correct solution to handle http status codes on both server side and client side.

**SERVER SIDE**

```
switch(Math.floor(statusCode/100)){
    case 2: 
        err.status = 'OK'
        break;
    case 4: 
        err.status = 'CLIENT ERROR';
        break;     
    case 5: 
        err.status = 'SERVER ERROR';
        
}


res.status(statusCode).json({
    status: status,            
    message: message   
    data: data
});
```

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
const res = axios.get('https://www.example.com/things);

if(res.data.status == 'OK'){
    showThings(res.data.data);
    console.log('Request successfully processed.');

} else if(res.data.status == 'CLIENT ERROR') {
    console.log('Request failed due to client error');

} else if(res.data.status == 'SERVER ERROR') {  
    console.log('Request failed due to server error.');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An API can return any status code it wishes to. Whether you have to handle it or not is a matter of the contract between your system and the API: ideally, a well-documented API will list all possible status codes it can return, eliminating the guesswork.

In most real-world cases, though, you can assume anything in the 200-299 range "succeeded", and anything else did not. Your distinction between 4xx and 5xx is correct. 3xx's are a little weird, as a 301/302 means you might just need to follow the redirect, and sometimes a 304 Not Modified will still mean the operation succeeded, but it depends on the API's implementation. 1xx's are not expected in a REST API.

Lastly, remember that while each status code has a meaning, they're only as meaningful as the API makes them. I have seen many production APIs that return 200s even for error responses, instead pushing the error status down into the body payload. Take care when generalizing your error handling to still allow the callers to access the original response for edge cases like these.

Comment: You probably meant `204 No Content` as 304 relates to `Not Modified`

Comment: Note further, most of those so called "REST APIs" have nothing to do with REST at all, but are truly RPC APIs exposed over HTTP. Not sure why so many people confuse REST with anything HTTP related. Such APIs may also use own, custom status codes that may not make any sense to any other, generic HTTP client. Also, stating that clients may ignore certain status codes is also a bit risky as i.e. a client could send a `Expect: 100-continue` header with a request to ask the server to check the request for any problems, if the server response with `100 Continue` the client can proceed.

Comment: I.e. imagine that you need to upload a huge file and you don't know if the server is able to handle it. You could send a PUT request with empty payload but with a content-length header of the size of the file to upload plus the before mentioned `Expect` header. If the server responds with `100 Continue` the client knows that the server is able to handle such large files and can finally send the whole file. After all, HTTP is still only a remote file management protocol [where business rules are just a side effect of the document managment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=191s)

Answer (score 4):

IANA is the entity that takes care of administrating all of the standardized [HTTP operations](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml), [link-relations](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) and [status-codes](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml).

As such currently IANA has the following status codes registered:

#### 1XX

- 100 Continue
- 101 Switching Protocols
- 102 Processing
- 103 Early Hints

#### 2XX

- 200 OK
- 201 Created
- 202 Accepted
- 203 Non-Authoritative Information
- 204 No Content
- 205 Reset Content
- 206 Partial Content
- 207 Multi-Status
- 208 Already Reported
- 226 IM Used

#### 3XX

- 300 Multiple Choices
- 301 Moved Permanently
- 302 Found
- 303 See Other
- 304 Not Modified
- 305 See Proxy
- 307 Temporary Redirect
- 308 Permanent Redirect

#### 4XX

- 400 Bad Request
- 401 Unauthorized
- 402 Payment Required
- 403 Forbidden
- 404 Not Fond
- 405 Method Not Allowed
- 406 Not Acceptable
- 407 Proxy Authentication Required
- 408 Request Timeout
- 409 Conflict
- 410 Gone
- 411 Length Required
- 412 Precondition Failed
- 413 Payload Too Large
- 414 URI Too Long
- 415 Unsupported Media Type
- 416 Range Not Satisfiable
- 417 Expectation Failed
- 421 Misdirected Request
- 422 Unprocessable Entity
- 423 Locked
- 424 Failed Dependency
- 425 Too Early
- 426 Upgrade Required
- 428 Precondition Required
- 429 Too Many Requests
- 431 Request Header Fields Too Large
- 451 Unavailable For Legal Reasons

#### 5XX

- 500 Internal Server Error
- 501 Not Implemented
- 502 Bad Gateway
- 503 Service Unavailable
- 504 Gateway Timeout
- 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
- 506 Variant Also Negotiates
- 507 Insufficient Storage
- 508 Loop Detected
- 510 Not Extended
- 511 Network Authentication Required

Any other status code you might receive are non-standardized customizations that might not be understood by generic HTTP clients.